# difference beеween compare array of char and pointer to char string with char string

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char* a  = "test";
    char b[] = "test";

    if ( a == "test" ) // work
      std::cout << "1";

    if ( b == "test" ) // don't
      std::cout << "2";
}
```

What exactly happend in both variants? Just memmory adress compare?

Comment: Related: Unless your compiler is smart enough to merge duplicate string constants (usually a configuration flag), `if ( a == "test" ) ` .. won't work either.

Comment: I wonder if `b == "test"` is legally allowed to be true, if this is the whole code. probably not

Comment: I'm btw.  surprised that the compiler allows `char* a  = "test";` That is valid c code, but invalid in c++, as a string literal has type `const char[N]`, which can be converted to `const char*` but not `char*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both cases you are not comparing the actual strings (use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) for this), but addresses:

1. In the first case, you are comparing the address stored in `a` - the start address of a string literal `"test"` - with the start address of a (conceptually) **different** string literal, that happens to have the same content. However, if there are multiple identical string literals in your code, the compiler is allowed to store them all in the same place to save memory and as a result, the comparison yields true (although this is not guaranteed to happen every time).
2. In the second case however, you are comparing the address of the first element of `b` with that of the string literal. Here, `b` is a local array that contains a copy of the string `"test"` but resides at a completely different memory region, so this comparison fails (and will always fail)

Note: Unless you have a very good reason not to, you should of course - as mentioned by PaulEvans - use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of an char array to store strings. This will give you all the nice value semantic properties and operator overloads you'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases you're comparing *pointers* not strings so it's blind luck any of them worked.

The best way to to compare strings is with `std::string`. Something like:

```
std::string c = "test";

if (c == "test") 
    std::cout << "c really is \"test\"!\n";
```